# Maintaining session in Android is not working

Tags: java, php, android, session, httprequest

I am trying to maintain the login info with session in android.
I am sure that all of my codes on the server are OK cause I have tested them with normal web browsers and also the android webview.

I have checked lots of similar questions on stackoverflow but none have worked for me so far.

here is what I have done...

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

try {
    //DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
    HttpContext httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    httpContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(urls[0]);
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

    //HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost, httpContext);
    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    InputStream is = httpEntity.getContent();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int ch;
    while ((ch = reader.read()) != -1)
        sb.append((char) ch);
    Content = sb.toString();

} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("JsonError", e.getMessage());
}

    return Content;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String page_output) {
Dialog.dismiss();
try {
    Log.i("data", page_output);

    TextView tv = (TextView) context.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    tv.setText(Content);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

can you please help me with this?

Comment: Please detail more what you have tried in order to increase your chances to be helped by others.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Session handling in HTML page using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479676/session-handling-in-html-page-using-javascript)

Comment: @yatin i checked that question they are not similar...

Comment: @Overdrivr the code is really simple on the server ... just a single php file in order to test session.. the first time that I send the post request the session will be set and should be available next times but it is not...