# How would I maintain a session with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, cookies, session-cookies

I am making a website where, upon loading, all elements are hidden except for a password box. When the user enters the correct password, the code reveals all the elements on the webpage. I would like to make it to where when the user reloads, the elements stay revealed after recognizing that the user has already entered the correct password. Below is my attempt at creating a cookie that stores the user's information and then using that cookie to make sure the page does not hide the elements again when the user reloads.

Thank you in advance!

```
<html>
<style>
h2 {
font-size: 50px;
color: green;
}
</style>

<body>
<div class="wsite-passwordBox">
<h1 id="header">Enter your name and the password</h1>
<input name="username" id ="username" onkeypress="return runScript(event)"></input>
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" onkeypress="return runScript(event)"></input>
<button id="button1">Enter</button>
<h2 id="smallHeader"></h2>
</div>
</body>

<script>
window.onload = function myFunction() {
var youtube = document.getElementsByClassName("wsite-youtube");
for (var i = 0; i < youtube.length; i ++) {
    youtube[i].style.display = "none";
}
var paragraph = document.getElementsByClassName("paragraph");
for (var i = 0; i < paragraph.length; i ++) {
    paragraph[i].style.display = "none";
}
var title = document.getElementsByClassName("wsite-content-title");
for (var i = 0; i < title.length; i++) {
    title[i].style.display = "none";
}
var spacer = document.getElementsByClassName("wsite-spacer");
for (var i = 0; i < spacer.length; i++) {
    spacer[i].style.display = "none";
}
var slideshow = document.getElementsByClassName("wslide");
for (var i = 0; i < slideshow.length; i++) {
    slideshow[i].style.display = "none";
}
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("wsite-multicol");
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].style.display = "none";
}
var form = document.getElementsByClassName("wsite-form-container");
for (var i = 0; i < form.length; i++) {
    form[i].style.display = "none";
}
var anotherButton = document.getElementsByClassName("wsite-button");
for (var i = 0; i < anotherButton.length; i++) {
    anotherButton[i].style.display = "none";
}
}

function testFunction() {
 
var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
        if (password == "test") {
checkCookie();
        var youtube = document.getElementsByClassName("wsite-youtube");
for (var i = 0; i < youtube.length; i ++) {
    youtube[i].style.display = "block";
}
var paragraph = document.getElementsByClassName("paragraph");
for (var i = 0; i < paragraph.length; i ++) {
    paragraph[i].style.display = "block";
}
var title = document.getElementsByClassName("wsite-content-title");
for (var i = 0; i < title.length; i++) {
    title[i].style.display = "block";
}
var spacer = document.getElementsByClassName("wsite-spacer");
for (var i = 0; i < spacer.length; i++) {
    spacer[i].style.display = "block";
}
var slideshow = document.getElementsByClassName("wslide");
for (var i = 0; i < slideshow.length; i++) {
    slideshow[i].style.display = "block";
}
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("wsite-multicol");
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].style.display = "block";
}
var form = document.getElementsByClassName("wsite-form-container");
for (var i = 0; i < form.length; i++) {
    form[i].style.display = "block";
}
var anotherButton = document.getElementsByClassName("wsite-button");
for (var i = 0; i < anotherButton.length; i++) {
    anotherButton[i].style.display = "block";
}
var passwordInputThing = document.getElementsByClassName("wsite-passwordBox") 
for (var i = 0; i < passwordInputThing.length; i++) {
    passwordInputThing[i].style.display = "none";
}
}
else {
document.getElementById("smallHeader").textContent = "Wrong password. Please try again.";
}
}
document.getElementById("button1").onclick = testFunction;
function runScript(e) {
    //See notes about 'which' and 'key'
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        testFunction();
    }
}




***function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
  var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}
function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}
function checkCookie() {
  var user = document.getElementById("username").value;
  if (user != "") {
    alert("Welcome, " + user);
  } else {
     user = prompt("Please enter your name:","");
     if (user != "" && user != null) {
       setCookie("username", user, 30);
     }
  }
}***
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Session handling in HTML page using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479676/session-handling-in-html-page-using-javascript)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This isn't what you asked but no doubt people will mention it. If you're doing this to keep secret things hidden, it is nowhere near secure as people can view the source and manipulate the JavaScript to enable everything. Just want to make sure you're aware.

Comment: @HazardousGlitch Yes, I am aware, thank you. I am a bit of a noob when it comes to HTML/CSS and keeping things encrypted (I am more comfortable with working in environments like Unity), and I'm not sure of how to do it any other way. Looking up things on the Internet yields so many different answers, so I just decided to do it this way. Thanks for pointing it out, though.

Comment: @Md.Amirozzaman It kind of does. I believe it's very similar to the cookie functions near the bottom of my code. I'm just not sure how to utilize it to where it will store that the user has entered their password, therefore when the page is loaded, the site should recognize that the user has been there before and entered their password and then reveal the elements to them.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I fully understood what kind of site you are building. Since the password in hardcoded in plain in the source code, it is one click away from an attacker.

Anyway I advise you to use localStorage (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) instead of cookies to store persistent client side data, since it is way easier to manipulate. (Just make sure the browser you are targeting are supported, since cookies are way older than localStorage).

localStorage uses string both as key and value. Use localStorage.getItem to retrieve a value (it returns null is the value is not defined) and localStorage.setItem to set a value.

You could use

```
localStorage.setItem("user", document.getElementById("username").value);
```

To save the user's name, and

```
localStorage.getItem("user");
```

to retrieve a previously saved user name.

Similarly you could use this to persist the fact that your user entered the correct password

```
localStorage.setItem("authenticated", "true");
```

And this in your onload function to check if the user previously entered the correct password:

```
if(localStorage.getItem("authenticated")===null) {
  // user is not authenticated
} else {
  // user is authenticated
}
```

Finally if you ever need to remove a value (e.g. clear authenticated) :

```
localStorage.removeItem("authenticated");
```

Comment: As a side note I would strongly encourage you to use === and !== for equality/inequality comparisons, since == and != display some rather "unexpected" behavior imbued with strange type conversions depending on the values you are comparing.